# Swift: Create button that leads to new view

Tags: swift, button, viewcontroller

I wanted to know how I'd programmatically, without the use of the storyboard, be able to make a button that when pressed leads you to another viewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
button.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.sizeToFit()
button.addTarget(self, action: "loadViewController", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

loadViewController is a method in your controller that loads another view controller.

```
func loadViewController()
{
    let vc = UIViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion:nil)
}
```